# Custom Authentication provider with Spring Security and Java Config

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

How can I define a custom Authentication provider by using Spring Security with Java Configurations?
I would like to perform a login checking credentials on my own database.

Comment: spring security documentations gives you all the info you need - how to configure your configuration' XML and endpoints.

in addition, you will have to support flows like "create account", "forgot password", etc, which you can use this open source: https://github.com/OhadR/oAuth2-sample/tree/master/authentication-flows

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The following does what you need (`CustomAuthenticationProvider` is your implementation which needs to be managed by Spring)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /**
         * Do your stuff here
         */
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to register a custom authentication provider in addition to the existing ones?

Comment: @Seppl I dont think that something like that exists out of the box (although I could easily be mistaked), but I'm pretty sure that something like that could be implemented relatively easily. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36417101/2504224)

Comment: According to the Spring Docu, `auth.authenticationProvider()` will "Add authentication based upon the custom AuthenticationProvider that is passed in." I'd guess that you get a stack of providers in this way.

Answer (score 8):

As shown on [baeldung.com](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider), define your authentication provider as follow:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
      throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (shouldAuthenticateAgainstThirdPartySystem(username, password)) {

            // use the credentials
            // and authenticate against the third-party system
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
              name, password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(
          UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

and following code is corresponding java config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("org.project.security")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(
      AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: You just copied that straight from http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider . While the answer is certainly helpful,  attributing sources is necessary as well.