# spring security custom inject AuthenticationProvider inside AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-java-config

Might be a newbie question. I want to inject CustomAuthenticationProviderInside Spring AuthenticationManager. I found a lot of examples online doing that:

```
<authentication-manager>

    <authentication-provider ref="CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>

</authentication-manager>
```

How can I do that using Java Config class?

Comment: refer the example for CustomerAuthenticationManager. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826233/custom-authentication-manager-with-spring-security-and-java-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Spring offers one default implementation of AuthenticationManager which is ProviderManager. ProviderManager has a constructor which takes an array of Authentication providers

```
public ProviderManager(List<AuthenticationProvider> providers) {
    this(providers, null);
}
```

If you want you can just play with it by extending ProviderManager

```
public class MyAuthenticationManager extends ProviderManager implements AuthenticationManager{

public MyAuthenticationManager(List<AuthenticationProvider> providers) {
    super(providers);
    providers.forEach(e->System.out.println("Registered providers "+e.getClass().getName()));
   }
}
```

And then i Java security configuration you can add your custom authentication manager.

```
@Override
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return new MyAuthenticationManager(Arrays.asList(new CustomAuthenticationProvider()));
}
```