# Securing rest API using Spring security custom Authentication Manager

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I am trying to provide the security of the rest API using spring custom Authentication manager. Now the problem when I am trying to access the url through postman its is showing **Access Denied Exception because user is anonymous**. Now my requirement is  every request for accessing that API should go to custom Security Manager. I have my own logic to validate. I will validate the request is valid or not depending on the Input json parameter. My config xml showing below.

```
 <security:http use-expressions="true"> 
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/persons" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
            <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
                  <security:http-basic/>
        </security:http>

        <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationManager" />
        </security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Authentication Manager with Spring Security and Java Configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826233/custom-authentication-manager-with-spring-security-and-java-configuration)

Comment: @IssamELATIF It is not the same question..

Comment: Gets your customAuthenticationManager invoked when you send the request with Postman?, what is the result of your customAuthenticationManager? do you send the basic auth information with postman?