# Authentication based on custom token

Tags: java, spring-security

I am trying to put in place an authentication based on a custom token in the request header.

I have read the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794680/multiple-authentication-mechanisms-in-a-single-app-using-java-config) and created a custom token, filter and authentication provider.

**Problem** :

When I try to "GET /login" :

- The filter is called
- The token is created
- The authenticationProvider is not called. Even its method `supports` is not called!

In the browser console, I can see 2 `HTTP 302` calls to `/login`.

Any idea?

**EDIT** : Actually, the authentication provider is ignored only if I call the endpoint from angular (resulting in an AJAX/XHR call). If I call the endpoint from Postman, the authentication provider is called.

**EDIT** : Spring security DEBUG logs :

```
2016-10-27 19:57:46.724 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.725 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.725 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2016-10-27 19:57:46.725 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-10-27 19:57:46.725 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.725 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@43bffae5
2016-10-27 19:57:46.725 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.725 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.725 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MyFilter'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.726 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-10-27 19:57:46.726 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-10-27 19:57:46.768 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.769 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.769 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2016-10-27 19:57:46.770 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-10-27 19:57:46.770 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.771 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@43bffae5
2016-10-27 19:57:46.771 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.771 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.771 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MyFilter'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.772 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession being created as SecurityContext is non-default
2016-10-27 19:57:46.774 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@17085d: Authentication: com.mycompany.myapp.configuration.MyToken@17085d: Principal: null; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: null; Not granted any authorities'
2016-10-27 19:57:46.774 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

**Token :**

```
public class MyToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

    private String token;

    public MyToken(String token) {
        super(null);
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Filter :**

```
public class MyFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public MyFilter() {
        super("/login");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String x_token = request.getHeader("x_token");
        String method = request.getMethod();
        if(x_token != null && method.equals("GET")) {
            return new MyToken(x_token);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Authentication provider :**

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        MyToken token = (MyToken) authentication;
        if(token.getCredentials() != null) {
            token.setAuthenticated(true);
            return token;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(MyToken.class);
    }
}
```

And finally, **the security configuration** :

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyAuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        // configure filters
        http.addFilterBefore( new MyFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class );

        // configure authentication providers
        http.authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider);

        // disable csrf
        http.csrf().disable();

        // setup security
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: @dur Added spring-security DEBUG logs. Also, I found out that if I call the endpoint with a regular request instead of XHR, the authentication provider is called.

Comment: @dur Did not know about this class and do not have it. I tried to declare one but it is not called. I looked at the following question and found that the accepted answer consists in building an `AuthenticationManager` by giving a list of `AuthenticationProvider`. It seems to be the same thing as giving an `AuthenticationProvider` to `HttpSecurity`, isn't it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826233/custom-authentication-manager-with-spring-security-and-java-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `AuthenticationManager`in your custom subclass of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#form-login-flow-handling):

> The filter calls the configured `AuthenticationManager` to process each authentication request.

See also [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter#attemptAuthentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#attemptAuthentication-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-):

> Performs actual authentication.
>   The implementation should do one of the following:
>
> 1. Return a populated authentication token for the authenticated user, indicating successful authentication
> 2. Return null, indicating that the authentication process is still in progress. Before returning, the implementation should perform any additional work required to complete the process.
> 3. Throw an `AuthenticationException` if the authentication process fails

Your implementation doesn't return an authenticated token, see logs:

> SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@17085d: Authentication: com.mycompany.myapp.configuration.MyToken@17085d: Principal: null; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; **Authenticated: false**; Details: null; Not granted any authorities'

See also:

- [`GaeAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/xml/gae/src/main/java/samples/gae/security/GaeAuthenticationFilter.java)
- [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/4.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java#UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29)
- [`OpenIDAuthenticationFilter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-openid/4.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/openid/OpenIDAuthenticationFilter.java#OpenIDAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29)
- [`CasAuthenticationFilter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-cas/4.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/cas/web/CasAuthenticationFilter.java#CasAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29)