# Don't know how configure access in spring boot security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

**EDIT 5**

Silly me, the ADMIN was not recognized 'cause I wrote the authoritiesByUsernameQuery query wrong: so if you have the same problem check this out.
Now configure in working: here code for example

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/admin", "/admin/user").access("hasRole('ADMIN')") /**only ADMIN can see those pages**/
    .antMatchers("/page*").access("hasRole('USER')") /**only the users can see all the pages that start with 'page'**/
    .anyRequest().permitAll() /**all the other pages can seen by anyone**/
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
    .and()
    .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
    .and()
    .csrf();
}
```

---

**EDIT 4**

If I wrote

```
${pageContext.request.isUserInRole('ADMIN')}
```

or

```
${pageContext.request.isUserInRole('USER')}
```

in my jsp it give it show "false", so it's not recognizing the roles. But why?

---

**EDIT 3**

Ok, now I have a new problem (plus the previous one): how can I permit access to everyone to some pages? Otherwise no user could subscribe.

---

**EDIT 2**

I edited the code again, following dur suggestion:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/admin", "/admin/users").access("hasRole('ADMIN')") 
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
    .and()
    .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
    .and()
    .csrf();
}
```

but it's still not working (the admin is not recognized and can't access to his pages). So, I don't think it's a problem only of the RULE_ADMIN.

In my database (postgres) I have created the tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.utenti
(
  username character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  password character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  abilitazione boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  email character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT username PRIMARY KEY (username)
)

CREATE TABLE public.ruoli_utente
(
  user_role_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ruoli_utente_user_role_id_seq'::regclass),
  username character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  ruolo character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT user_role_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_role_id),
  CONSTRAINT username_fk FOREIGN KEY (username)
      REFERENCES public.utenti (username) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

It's possible that authoritiesByUsernameQuery method didn't recognize the role column because it's called differently? If so, why usersByUsernameQuery recognize enabled users, since I called the column 'abilitazione' instead of 'enabled'?

---

**EDIT**

Maybe I'm starting understanding, I've changed my method like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/hello").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")      
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")  
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
        .csrf();
}
```

but it doesn't recognize the admin user.

---

I'm following [this guide](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-4-authenticate-and-authorize-users) to add security in my Spring Boot web application.
I'm having a problem in the `configure` method inside my security class, and it's hard to me to understand how solve it searching online.

What I want to do is permit the access at all the pages if the user is authenticated, excepts for the admin page.

This is what I wrote:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/adminPage").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')");  
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout") 
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
        .csrf();
}
```

but it's not working, and I can't understand why/how should I do, neither I'm finding the solution online (or it's not working/I don't understand it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatcher("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    .antMatchers("/adminPage").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    ...;
}
```

Then write your own AutenticationManager somehow like that :
[Custom Authentication Manager with Spring Security and Java Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826233/custom-authentication-manager-with-spring-security-and-java-configuration)

And create your own object User that `extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` with appropritate `username, password, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>{{ add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")}}` 
(and `add(new SimplaGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))` if the user is an admin).

You will probably have to implement a UserDetailsService also.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I would like to avoid this method if possible, to keep the project simple.