# Java Spring reject non-active users from logging in

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am attempting to generate an error message for users that are currently not validated. These users should get an message, which is shown at `/login?error`. It already goes to this url when the user authentication goes wrong, but this is obviously done in the authentication success handler. This is the success handler:

```
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

How would I go about still returning to an error page when the authentication is successful, but the user is set on inactive? I assume it should be done in this function. All help is welcome!

EDIT: The idea is to check users for their `active` status. Each user has a field 'active' in the database, which will be set true by an admin. How spring is currently configured, is that the `onAuthenticationSuccess` handler will be called, since the credentials are good. I actually want to reject the user from logging in when the user has active = false

Comment: What do you mean by "users that are currently not validated"?

Comment: @VHS Users have a field which states if they are validated or not. I can just access this as user.getActive() and get either true or false. The credentials to log in will work just fine, as this is handled just by standard security. I actually want to direct them to an error page when the user active status is false. I am a novice Java/Spring user, so there might be a solution already :<

Comment: Session is authenticated in `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#attemptAuthentication`.

Comment: Are you not using Spring Security? If you are, there's a built-in field for disabling user accounts.

Comment: @chrylis I am, but I'm just not at all familiar with Java/Spring yet. It's only a question of checking the user.getActive() and returning to something like `/login?error`. I'm not aware of any existing functions for this

Comment: I suggest you use authentication manager.
See [Custom Authentication Manager with Spring Security and Java Configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826233/custom-authentication-manager-with-spring-security-and-java-configuration)

Comment: The `UserDetails` interface has a flag for disabling accounts, which is automatically handled by the standard Spring Security components.

Comment: Spring Security does that by default... If that isn't working you have bypassed parts of Spring Security that you shouldn't have bypassed.