# Basic Spring security errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring application and all I am trying to do is add all the default headers to it which Spring Security provides. My web.xml changes are as follows:

```
<!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My spring-security.xml is as follows:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <headers />
    </http>

</beans:beans>
```

I am seeing the following errors on startup

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' is defined: Did you forget to add a gobal  element to your configuration (with child  elements)? Alternatively you can use the authentication-manager-ref attribute on your  and  elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it something to authenticate users. Try adding

```
<user-service>
        <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</user-service>
```

To your security xml and see the example [here.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/helloworld-xml.html)

Comment: I don't need any username or password in my application. Should I still add this?

Comment: Well, no haha. But you need *some* sort of `AuthenticationManager` as the security framework expects it. I've built all kinds of these that use tokens, OAuth, etc. It definitely can be done, you just have to research the specific use case. Either way, you do need an `AuthenticationManager` instance

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826233/custom-authentication-manager-with-spring-security-and-java-configuration

Comment: I just need the headers. Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: @p0tta If you just need the headers, I'd create your own filter and set them yourself. Spring Security is going to come with a whole host of other stuff that you don't need

Comment: That makes sense. Any helpful articles that you can point me to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141482/discussion-between-chris-thompson-and-p0tta).

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the SecurityConfig java class to disable Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF). This is enabled by default:

```
   @EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.csrf().disable();
       //You can continue extending this method call . e.g. calling 
       //authorizeRequests()
       http.headers().xssProtection();

        }
    }
```