# Implementing Custom Authentication in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I would like to ask for your help regarding my problem in Spring Security.
I have a requirement wherein I have to validate a login credential based on the option selected by the user. Option 1 would be validating the logged in user via third party service. Option 2 would be the normal validation using database authentication level. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 13):

> **General Strategy**

1. Provide a custom implementation of `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider` that delegates authentication to the appropriate backend (third-party service, another `AuthenticationProvider`, etc.).
2. Pass the user-selected option to the custom `AuthenticationProvider`, enabling it to choose the correct authentication backend.
3. Configure the custom `AuthenticationProvider` as the default authentication provider.

---

> **Step 1: Implement `AuthenticationProvider`**

`AuthenticationProvider` is an interface with a single method.  Therefore, a custom implementation may look like:

```
class DelegatingAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
  @Autowired
  private ThirdPartyAuthenticationService service;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("anotherAuthenticationProvider")
  private AuthenticationProvider provider;

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    // Get the user selection.
    String selection = (String) authentication.getDetails();

    // Take action depending on the selection.
    Authentication result;
    if("ThirdParty".equals(selection)) {
      // Authenticate using "service" and generate a new
      // Authentication "result" appropriately.
    }
    else {
      // Authenticate using "provider" and generate a new
      // Authentication "result" appropriately.
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

> **Step 2: Pass the user selection to the `AuthenticationProvider`**

The `AuthenticationProvider` implementation above picks up the user selection from the `details` property of the `Authentication` object.  Presumably, the user selection would have to be picked up from the `HttpServletRequest` and added to the `Authentication` object before the `AuthenticationProvider` is invoked.  This means, another component that has access to both the `Authentication` and `HttpServletRequest` objects needs to be invoked before the `AuthenticationProvider` is called.

The `Authentication` object is created by an implementation of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.  This class has a method named `attemptAuthentication` that accepts an `HttpServletRequest` object and returns an `Authentication` object.  So it seems this would be a good candidate for implementing what is needed.  For username-password based authentication, the implementation class is `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.  This class returns a new instance of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, which is an implementation of `Authentication`.  So, a class extending `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` should be sufficient.

```
class ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    ...
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    authentication.setDetails(obtainUserSelection(request));

    ...

    return authentication;
  }
}
```

`obtainUserSelection` is a private method that gets the user selection out of the request.

> **Step 3: Configuration**

Configure the `AuthenticationProvider` and filter implementations in the Spring Security configuration.  The exact steps will vary depending on whether XML or Java configuration is used.

Comment: wow..thanks manish! this is one heck of a ride learning spring security. This is my first implementation by the way. can you point me to a tutorial site on implementing the ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter? please :)

Comment: You can review [the official implementation of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java).